# Possible to call Marketing Cloud via a proxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, fuel-sdk

I am using the fuelSDK for Java. At the moment I am creating an ETClient bean which sets up the client for Marketing Cloud and I can access my data extensions. I want to now access Marketing Cloud via proxy.

App -> Proxy -> Marketing Cloud

Is this possible?

I've tried setting the endpoint on the ETConfiguration object as the proxy url and passing it as an argument when instantiating the ETClient objetc but for some reason ETClient object still defaults the endpoint to  `https://www.exacttargetapis.com`

Answer (score 1):

FuelSDK is not actively maintained and updated.  I am unsure when the last update has been made - it certainly does not have the functionality you desire built in.  The code base is downloadable, tho, so you can incorporate it into your application and make the changes you need - I have had to modify it quite a bit to meet my own needs.

Edit: As a more clear answer, if you want to call Marketing Cloud via Proxy, it should be doable but NOT via fuelSDK UNLESS you make your own modifications to the fuelSDK to enhance its functionality.

You can also use the Marketing Cloud SOAP wsdl to create your own communication layer in lieu of using fuelSDK.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/wsdl-endpoint-links.htm